# Taking 2D array input without space

Tags: java

I am trying to take input pattern matrix.Each
pattern dataset will consist of an integer on a line by itself, which gives the dimensions of the square
containing the pattern (the size will range from 1 to 10). The following lines will contain each line
of the 1st pattern and 2nd pattern in a side-by-side format, separated by a space. input will look like below

```
5
X...X ....X
.X... ...X.
...X. .X...
..X.X ..X..
....X XX..X
```

I have tried like below

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= input.nextInt();
                char [][] pattern1=new char[10][10];
                char [][] pattern2=new char[10][10];
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                        pattern1[i][j]=input.next().charAt(0);
                    }
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                        pattern2[i][j]=input.next().charAt(0);
                    }
                }
```

The problem is I have to hit extra space after each character. like this.

```
5
X . . . X . . . . X
. X . . . . . . X .
. . . X . . X . . .
. . X . X . . X . .
. . . . X X X . . X
```

But i need to read without extra space. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: What type is `input`? And what does the documentation for that type say that `next()` does?

Comment: I am taking `char` type input( dot(.) or cross(X)).

Comment: I suspect `input` is a `Scanner` -- but your question should have said what it is.

Comment: How are you printing the input out?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `input` is a `Scanner`, *that's what it does*. From its Javadoc:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

You use a Scanner *when you want to consume a **delimited** token one at a time*.

You could instead use a `DataInputStream`, which has `readChar()`.

Or you could stick with `Scanner` and use `nextLine()` to grab a line's worth of `X`s and `.`s, and loop through that `String`.

```
 String line = input.nextLine();
 for(int j=0; j<line.length(); j++) {
    pattern1[i][j]=line.charAt(j);
 }
```

But again, if you don't want to split on a delimiter, why on earth are you using a `Scanner`? That's literally its only purpose.